# In Free JQGrid how can i add a input field in column header

Tags: jqgrid

I have a requirement to add a input field in column header, the requirement is, upon checking some checkbox's(rows) of jqgrid user can simply type text value in a input field in column header which will be automatically populated to all its cell values below this column. Basically this will eliminate user's effort of entering values in each cell of that column.

Example: if i enter VICTE in column header then all the below cell values of that column should be auto populated with that VICTE value.

So how can i add a input field in column header ?

[image: see blow picture]

Answer (score 0):

In colNames array you can put any valid html content including input fields. After that it is easy to bind any event you want knowing the id of the input fields. By example you can write

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
   ...
   colNames : ['ShipName',...,'<input id="id1" type="text">',...]
   ...
});
```